# Who's the random kid standing in the gathering at the end?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, there's a gathering...

> for Tony Stark's funeral.

During it, they move the camera over several characters, often Avengers grouped together. One person they pan over is a single teenager with brown hair. Who is that character?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Harley Keener](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Harley_Keener). He is the kid in Iron Man 3 who helps Tony Stark.

[Source](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/1118372/Avengers-Endgame-spoilers-kid-boy-Tony-Stark-funeral-who-Harley-Keener-Ty-Simpkins). The actors name is also in the end credits.

Comment: I must be face blind; I thought that was Spider Man.

Comment: @user Peter was shown with his aunt earlier in the scene